# JSONP response from WebAPI to Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, jsonp

I have a simple angular controller like below:

```
angular.module('widget.controllers', [])
  .controller('ProductController', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http) {

      $http.jsonp('http://localhost:27467/api/Products/GetProducts/EUR?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
      .success(function (data) {
          console.log(data);
      });

  }]);
```

along with a simple action in web api controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetProducts(string id)                
{
      var returnData = data;
      string callback = ControllerContext.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs().Where(kv => kv.Key == "callback").Single().Value;    
      return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, returnData, new JsonpMediaTypeFormatter(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter(),callback), new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/javascript"));
}
```

where I am using [this formatter](https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp). But the response is not containing the callback function's name wrapped around the JSON. It produces sth like:

```
({.....});
```

instead of:

```
myCallback({....});
```

Please suggest for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) to have control over which apis to allow CORS or not. Epic!